# Getting the timestamp wrong firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

Hey I am trying to get the current TIMESTAMP in the app when clicking a button but the TIMESTAMP is incorrect. The TIMESTAMP sometimes shows the time ahead and sometimes 10 minutes before time. Here is the code

```
timestapmReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final long timeStampLong = (long) dataSnapshot.child("time").child("timestampQuestionSeen").getValue();
        final DatabaseReference questionSeenReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("questions").
                child(imagename);

        questionSeenReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild("questionSeen")) {

                    questionSeenReference.child("questionSeenTime").setValue(timeStampLong);
                    questionSeenReference.child("questionSeen").setValue("1");


                }
                questionSeenReference.removeEventListener(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        timestapmReference.removeEventListener(this);
    }


    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
    timestapmReference.child("time").child("timestampQuestionSeen").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Are you testing your app on an emulator or on a real device?

Comment: I am testing it on a real device @AlexMamo

Comment: Using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a corect way set the timestamp and as i see, your code looks fine. Are your date and time correct set on your phone? Check your phone settings and compare it with the time of your computer.

Comment: I have checked that as well its correct at all places also the time is sometimes ahead by 20 seconds and  going back as 10 min so that couldn't be the case if my time was incorrect.  @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are setting those values insider the `onDataChange` method. There is no need to do such a thing. Move this 2 lines:

```
questionSeenReference.child("questionSeenTime").setValue(timeStampLong);                                        
questionSeenReference.child("questionSeen").setValue("1");
```

outside that method and remove that listener because is useless. To set a value you only need to use the `setValue()` method directly on the `reference`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked the database the value set in the timestamp from server is wrong

Comment: When you are using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, you are setting in your database the `time` and `date` of that moment. If you are checking 10 minutes later, in your database the timestamp will ramain the same. But in order to set it correctly, please do as explained above.

Comment: but I would need to check whether the user has already seen the question @Alex

Comment: Ok, in this case you need to add a new field named `isSeen` of type `boolean` and set it `false` if the user haven't seen the question and `true` otherwise. You also can add another `timestamp` which will represent the time when the question was seen. So when you set the `isSeen` field to `true`, in the same time you can set `seenTimestamp` with the time and date, off the action that has occurred.

Comment: The time is fine. I was actually comparing it the wrong way @AlexMamo

Comment: Actually the problem was that sometimes a value of time was null. which resulted in showing the incorrect time. Your solution could most defininately solve someone else's problem. +1 for that